# What's the right approach to load partial functionalities on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a complex angular app with some functionality that shouldn't be there by default. There are some forms that should only be seen when some button is clicked or some configuration is active (lets call this "partials"). Take this simplified example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('controller', function() {
    var partial_html = "<input>bla bla";
    var float_partial_html = "<input>ble ble";

    this.show_random_gen = function() {
      //load a partial on .partial
    }
    this.show_random_float_gen = function() {
      //load another partial on .partial
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
  <p>Other stuff....</p>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.show_random_gen()">Gen Random</button>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.show_random_float_gen()">Gen Random Float</button>
</div>
<div class="partial">

</div>
```

In the example you have an interface, with other functions (represented by "Other stuff...") and then you have 2 buttons. Each one should load an extra functionality. My point is: what is the best way to do it?

I can think of, at least, 2 ways, some simpler, some uglier:

- Have those modules as separeted partials, currently on the html, with their models and data on the main controller and simply hide/show them on click.
- Load them as html external templates with different angular module or controller.

The second approach seems better for bigger applications but I don't know how to implement it. What is the right approach to solve this?

Comment: This is unclear of what are your intentions. Maybe you should have a look at ngRoute and ui-router. Both provide you with a solution that is somewhat a combination of both your suggestions.

Comment: @MuliYulzary I took a look at what you said but I'm not sure because for routing you need the controllers already implemented in your app, and when you load a view you just attatch them to it. For performance reasons, I thought they both could be loaded on demand...

Comment: They can. check this out: https://oclazyload.readme.io/